# How to pass PHP Variable to an included File?

Tags: php, variables

I have a Formmailer and want to throw an error, when the E-Mail Address in the Database already exists:

**formmailer.php**

```
$email        = $_POST["email"];
```

In case of an error the formmailer throws:

```
include_once('failed.php');
```

**failed.php**

```
Your email address $email already exists.
```

But the Output is still $email and not the real value. Regarding to the Docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it should work:

*When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs.*

I also tried to set the variables as global

```
global $email;
```

But this has no effect!

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything outside of the PHP tags is output directly and raw to the HTTP response.

If you want to use PHP code, including variables, it has to go between PHP tags.

(And don't output user input raw: It opens you up to XSS attacks).

```
Your email address <?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?> already exists.
```

Comment: Its an internal website and I use Regex inside the formmailer to avoid dangerous characters.

Comment: Thanks solved! I was thinking, including an external file is already withhin the <?php> tags